# Entity framework "Field required" Error but works fine in debuuging

Tags: entity-framework, debugging, lazy-loading, required-field

I have got a strange error in entityframework when I am trying to update an entity which uses some virtual (lazy load) properties. I retrieve the entity from the database and change a one to one property in that then try to update it again.The exception for some of the virtual properties is The field is required while others don't have this error. 
What makes everything even more strange is that when I try to inspect the entity in debug mode the code just works fine and I don't face any errors at all.
Has anyone else experienced such behavior?

Thanks

Here is what code looks like:

```
public class IndependenceCheck : ModelBase
{
        [Key]
        public int IndependenceCheckID { get; set; }

        public int PrincipalCompanyID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("PrincipalCompanyID")]
        public virtual Company PrincipalCompany { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OrganizationAddressID")]
        [Required]
        public virtual Address OrganizationAddress { get; set; }

}
```

There are much more fields in model, while I try to update no errors for PrincipalCompany occurs but for OrganizationAddress I got the required field error.

Comment: Can you give an example code block?

Comment: Actually the classes are a little bit big... but it is something like this:

Comment: I think, OrganizationAddressID property is required, but not the OrganizationAddress itself.

Comment: That was weird but worked! Thanks mate. You can answer it if you like and I will mark it :)